# Products are not adding in compare list in magento2?

Tags: magento2, compare

I have to implement product compare feature in my magento2. For this i am using

`<?php $this->getAddUrl($product); ?>` and I am getting the compare url of the product. But after click on `add to compare` link, no product showing in the compare sidebar.

Please help me to do it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any error in browser console or var log?

Comment: nop..no any kind of error. only page is refresh after click on `add to compare` link and also i tried to `echo $_helper->getItemCount() ;` and getting `You have no items to compare.` message.

Comment: You can give us an product compare url sample from your custom?

Comment: `http://localhost/magento_folder/catalog/product_compare/add/product/2379/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvMl90d3Avd2lyZS1tZXNoLW1hdGVyaWFsL2JyYXNz/` this is the url of product which i have to compare. in this url 2379 is the product id, and aHR0cDov.....XNz is the encoded url. After click on this url, the product should add in compare sidebar. but its not adding right now.

Comment: You use `http://localhost/`?

Comment: its just a url which i am getting in `add to compare` anchor tag. I don't think so that the problem is due to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49141/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-yudi).